# use tokenize_and_parse with boost::spirit::line_pos_iterator or boost::spirit::classic::position_iterator2

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, lexer

How can I use boost::spirit::lex::tokenize_and_parse with with those iterators?
All examples seem to use string iterators.

Actually I want to use iterators from a std::istream object instead of copying the whole file content into a string.

Comment: I just want to use my parser as before with the exception of using a separate Lexer so I need to pass the same stream objects as before.

Comment: I think you want `lexer::pos_iterator`

See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16931098/85371 (just showing a sample that it can be done)

Comment: I want to use iterators of a std::istream object instead of std::string. Do I always have to copy the whole file content into one string before?