# Making Boost Spirit grammar stateless

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

As recommended here: [How to benchmark Boost Spirit Parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918831/how-to-benchmark-boost-spirit-parser)
I want to make my grammar stateless, static and const.
Therefore I have to store the current column, row and result somewhere and I thought locals would be the right place. Unfortunately, I cannot access locals of the parent rule in a sub rule to modify them:

```
  qi::rule<Iterator, qi::locals<Slk::Table::size_type, Slk::Table::size_type, Slk::Table> > cells;
cells =
            eps[ref(_b) = 1][ref(_a) = 1]
```

now I want to change the locals in a sub rule:

```
f_record =
            lit('F')
            >> +(
                skipped_field
                | y_field[ref(_a) = _1]
                | x_field[ref(_b) = _1]
            )
        ;
```

but how can I access the locals from the parent rule? Do I have to store them in the attribute?!
What's the best way to make the grammar stateless? Where do I store variables of the current state which might be modified by ANY sub rule anywhere in the grammar at any time?

Comment: You can pass references to attributes/locals down to subrules using _inherited attributes_.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? And no, your prose above does not make that clear. Consider showing a simple minimalist example instead.

Comment: thx passing references using inherited attributes was exactly what I was looking for. I am trying to achieve to pass locals of a rule to a sub rule. f_record is a sub sub rule of cells. Replacing ref(_a) in f_record by ref(_r1) and adding a inherited attribute of the type Slk::Table::size_type was what I was looking for.